# Working with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

I am currently working with a maintenance scheduling system of trucks, so this is the case, in my Truck Details Table, I have a kilometer run column, and in my Job Order Table, I have also a kilometer run column, i want to reference the Truck Details Table (Kilometer Run column) to my Job Order (Kilometer Run Column) and cascade its update. on sqlyog this appears (Cannot add foreign key constraint)

```
Alter table `pms`.`joborder`  
  add constraint `fk_jo_run` foreign key (`run`) references `pms`.`trucks`(`current_run`) on update Cascade
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the full error message.

Comment: (Cannot add foreign key constraint)

Alter table `pms`.`joborder`  
  add constraint `fk_jo_run` foreign key (`run`) references `pms`.`trucks`(`current_run`) on update Cascade

Comment: i would like to reverse my question, How can i connect my current kilometer run in my Truck Details Table to my Job Order table, if my current kilometer run is not a primary key?

Comment: Edit your post ... show the table structure and then ask what you are trying to get.

Comment: s there any way to see the queries entered in sqlyog? because i entered it on forms not on query –

Answer (score 0):

*Out of guess*, I don't see any issue with your `ALTER` command except that a constraint named `fk_jo_run` may be already existing. So try giving a different name to your constraint like

```
Alter table `pms`.`joborder`  
  add constraint `fk_jobOrder_Trucks_run` foreign key (`run`) 
references `pms`.`trucks`(`current_run`) on update Cascade;
```

Comment: is there any way to see the queries entered in sqlyog? because i entered it on forms not on query

Comment: @JohnPaulCirilos what do you mean `you entered it on form not on query?` Also, when you execute a query from the query editor in sqlyog you should get a response in the message window on the bottom...if you want to see actual query running go to `tools>show>processlist`...However, we REALLY need to see your table structure to be of anymore help here ...

Comment: @BK435 i have entered it by adding new table, i dont input manual queries